# python **kwags Error: function takes 6 positional arguments but 8 were given

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, gradient-descent

When I was trying to develop a gradient descent, I discovered an interesting problem that I cannot use **kwargs effectively. My function looks like

```
def gradient_descent(g,x,y,alpha,max_its,w,**kwargs):    
    # switch for verbose
    verbose = True
    if 'verbose' in kwargs:
        verbose = kwargs['verbose']

    # determine num train and batch size
    num_train = y.size()[1]
    batch_size = num_train
    if 'batch_size' in kwargs:
        batch_size = kwargs['batch_size']
    ........
```

and the Error looks like:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f71adb8a241b> in <module>()
  3 w_train = Variable(torch.Tensor(w_init), requires_grad=True)
  4 g = softmax; alpha_choice = 10**(-1); max_its = 100; num_pts = y.size; 
batch_size = 10;
----> 5 weight_hist_2,train_hist_2 = gradient_descent(g,x_train,y_train,alpha_choice,max_its,w_train,num_pts,batch_size,verbose = False)
```

**TypeError: gradient_descent() takes 6 positional arguments but 8 were given.**

Is there anything I didn't notice for developing this function?

Comment: Can you show the call to gradient_descent. Because this is where the error occured. You forgot to pass in some argument, not kwargs.

Answer (score 2):

Your function signature doesnt match the number of parameter you are using it with:

```
gradient_descent(g,x,y,alpha,max_its,w,**kwargs)
```

has 6 positional argumens `g,x,y,alpha,max_its,w` but, in your call:

```
gradient_descent(g,x_train,y_train,alpha_choice,max_its,w_train,num_pts,batch_size,verbose = False)
```

You are giving it 8 `g,x_train,y_train,alpha_choice,max_its,w_train,num_pts,batch_size`

I guessed you wanted to use `num_pts` as the `batch_size` argument, so it will look like this:

```
weight_hist_2,train_hist_2 = gradient_descent(
    g,
    x_train,
    y_train,
    alpha_choice,
    max_its,
    w_train,
    batch_size=num_pts,
    verbose = False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. It's really helpful!